# Python: How to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the first 3 <li> elements of a ul=class?

Tags: python

I am using the following script to scrape information to create  postal mailing labels.

The script scrapes all the data from the `ul` class "description keywords" tag of my counties PUBLIC tax database.

My problem is how do I only scrape the first 3 `li` elements of the `ul` class "description key." Take in mind that this class is used over a 100 times in the html and I only need the first 3 elements that contains the mailing address information.

What do I need to add to get only the `li` elements that I need?

The script works well, but it grabs too much information.

Thanks

The following line of code grabs all the data I need, but also gives 2 extra `li` elements that I do not need.

```
a = soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "description keywords"})
```

I need to only collect the first 3 `li` elements of the `ul` class-"description keywords"

Comment: Have you tried `soup.find(attrs={"class" : "description keywords"}).findAll('li', limit=3)`?

Comment: Thank you. This only gives the first address, but not all the rest on the page. It does give me the 3 lines that I need, but only for the first instance of the class = "description keywords".

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find_all('title', limit=1)
```

You can set a limit to `find_all`.  This won't actually make your code much faster, since `find_all` is still called-- it just returns fewer results.  For actual faster processing, you can call `find_next` three times.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree

Comment: I couldn't get find_all or find_next to work at all. When I use findAll('li', limit=3) all it does is give me the result for the first address. It does not go through the entire file. For every keyword description is displayed I need the first 3 li elements. It gives me the 1st 3 elements that I need, but stops at the first instance of ul = keyword description. I will read some more and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: You need to return a list of elements of every file, and then run find_all with limit=3 for each of those elements.